# Como não serializar determinado tipo de elemento com jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tenho um formulário e não quero "serializar" os *input's* do tipo *checkbox*, logo tentei algumas opções tais como abaixo:

```
var form = $('#service-item-form :not(:input[type="checkbox"])').serialize();
```

Mas infelizmente não funciona! Gostaria de saber o que posso tentar fazer para resolver essa questão.

Comment: Relacionada em inglês: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4556172/excluding-certain-inputs-on-serialize

Comment: @WallaceMaxters, infelizmente não funcionou.

Comment: Posta o código do seu formulário, porque tem algum erro na sua pergunta. As respostas foram testadas e funcionam corretamente.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

De acordo com a resposta do [SOEN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4556172/excluding-certain-inputs-on-serialize):

```
$('#ofform').on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var serializedReturn = $('input[name!=security]', this).serialize();        
});
```

Eu iria preferir dessa forma, utilizando o `not`:

```
$("form").find(":input").not(':checkbox').serialize()
```

Comment: Deu certa a ultima opção Wallace!

Answer (score 4):

Experimenta o seguinte:

```
var form = $('#service-item-form')
    .find('input, textarea, select')
    .not(':checkbox')
    .serialize()
```

Comment: infelizmente não funcionou.

Comment: @JoãoManolo de certeza que o id no HTML é "service-item-form"

Comment: Sim! Obrigado pela ajuda, mas a resposta do @Wallace Maxters deu certo.